# Getting twitter followers' usernames

Tags: java, twitter

I am working with TwitterFactory like this:

```
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessToken(xxxxxxxxxxxxx )
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());


        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        long cursor = -1;

        IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(cursor);
```

The thing is that I do not want IDs but I need to get followers' usernames and I cannot figure out how?
Do you have any ideas of how am I supposed to get the usernames?

Update of code:

```
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessToken(xxxxxxxxxxxxx )
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());


        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        long cursor = -1;

        IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(cursor);

         long[] id = ids.getIDs();
            ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(id);               
            for (User user : users) {
                usernames.add(user.getScreenName());

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since getting the usernames is an additional call, here is a method I made that can call them in batches of 100.  For my usage I was mapping them to a static map, but you get the idea.

```
public static HashMap<Long,String> usernameMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();

public static void requestBatch(long[] batch,Twitter twitter) throws TwitterException
{
    ResponseList<User> responseList = twitter.lookupUsers(batch);
    for(User u : responseList){
        usernameMap.put(u.getId(), u.getScreenName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution with a little delay. But I get an error when calling lookupusers() which is "TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e39d013b-2e5d0c1b], statusCode=404, message=Sorry, that page does not exist, code=34, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=178, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1384761999, secondsUntilReset=819}, version=3.0.0}". Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: oh, lookup users throws a 404 if the userid doesnt exist.  You can catch and handle it with a catch(TwitterException te)

Comment: Thank you very much I made it work, with your help of course. I had made a ridiculous mistake passing the parameter batch. I have posted code in my initial post.

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether there's possibility to get the followers of my followers or friends of friends. Is this possible @frankie liuzzi ? I have also opened a new thread here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633781/get-second-level-features-of-social-network-through-twitter-api)  . Thank you in advance