# Get Second Level features of social network through Twitter Api

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to get second level features of my twitter personal network using twitter4j library. When I refer to second level features I mean the followers of my followers, the followees of my followees etc.

I've started with my followees first using the following code:

```
try{
    twitter = tf.getInstance();
    long cursor = -1;
    IDs ids = twitter.getFriendsIDs(cursor);

    long[] id = ids.getIDs();
    ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(id); 
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warn("Error {}",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using the above I am getting my friends. But I am struggling to get the friends of friends.
I've read that giving my twitter keys I am authorized to get second level features but not further that that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Let me write a sample below: First block is for finding followers of a particular tweet user.

    long lCursor = -1, nextCursor = -1;
    IDs friendsIDs = null;

    followerIDListOfOriginalTweeter = new ArrayList<>();

            do
            {
                lCursor = nextCursor;
                try
                {
                    friendsIDs = twitterObj.getFollowersIDs(originalTweetUserId, lCursor);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logWriter.Write(ex);
                }

                nextCursor = friendsIDs.getNextCursor();

             } while (nextCursor != 0);


The second block is for finding followers of followers:

    IDs friendsIDs = null;
    long lCursor = -1, nextCursor = -1;

    try
        {
            do
              {
                    followers = new Followers();

                    nextCursor = -1;

                    do
                    {
                        lCursor = nextCursor;

                        try
                        {
                friendsIDs = twitterObj.getFollowersIDs(followers.currentUserId, lCursor);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                          logWriter.Write(ex);

                        }

                        for (long followerId : friendsIDs.getIDs())
                        {                            
                           system.out.println(followerId);
                        }

                        nextCursor = friendsIDs.getNextCursor();

                    } while (nextCursor != 0);

            } while (rsForSelectNotCompletedRetweetsQuery.next());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Of course, one huge problem I am dealing with is that twitter returns error as I exceed the rate limits. Could you inform me if there is any possible solution for my case?

Comment: I know the rate limit issue is important, but there is a trick that you can use. The trick is you should create several twitter accounts and generate token info corresponding those new twitter accounts. You can catch that rate limit error in try-catch block, then you can renew the twitter object of Twitter class with the renewed token. What I am doing is that I stored all the token info in a db table, then I am reading and storing all info in a list object once. Then, for each rate-limit error, I am renewing token, then I will be able to use API functions without any rate-limit problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a very good approach, I think that I have read it somewhere here again, but in my case what I need is to get the list of followers of followers of one specific user that has just signed in. So, I guess I can't follow this workaround, can I?

Comment: One more questions, since I will create different accounts how can I take the followers of the specific user? Let's say I am using the tokens of 5 accounts circularly, I suppose that each time I 'll get the followers that correspond to one token that corresponds to one user. Is my thought correct?Thank you.